# How to create a nested dictionary based on Stage?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries and want to create a nested dict based on stages. The children should get appended in the parent node 
I am not understanding how to get the depth of the stage so as to append children. I am very novice developer.

The list is as follows.

```
{
    "PR" : [
            "OTP"
        ],
        "Sub_Dept" : [
            "Sales",
            "Call Center"
        ],
        "Type" : "Process Tree",
        "name" : "OTP",
        "Journey_Type" : "Process Tree",
        "line no" : [
            "4",
            "5",
            "6"
        ],
        "Text" : "sample",
        "Edit_status" : false,
        "Active_Status" : "Active",
        "New Journey" : [
            "matchotp",
            "get_policy_related_details"
        ],
        "Edit_Time" : "2019-08-19 16:36:10",
        "thread_length" : 2,
        "Journey_Name" : "SHORT",
        "Created_Time" : "2019-08-19 16:36:10",
        "Dept" : [
            "Sales",
            "Call Center"
        ],
        "Stage" : "0.1",
        "type" : "DTHyperlink",
        "id" : "1566212770287",
        "desc" : "sample"
    },

    /* 2 createdAt:8/19/2019, 4:36:10 PM*/
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d5a82a24db9f0528d446fa5"),
        "PR" : [ ],
        "Sub_Dept" : [
            "Sales",
            "Call Center"
        ],
        "Type" : "Process Tree",
        "name" : "Parent",
        "Parent" : true,
        "Journey_Type" : "Process Tree",
        "line no" : [
            "2"
        ],
        "Text" : "OTP has been sent to your registered mobile number and email id. Please enter the otp",
        "Edit_status" : false,
        "Active_Status" : "Active",
        "id" : "1566212770121",
        "Edit_Time" : "2019-08-19 16:36:10",
        "thread_length" : 1,
        "Created_Time" : "2019-08-19 16:36:10",
        "DT" : [
            "OTP"
        ],
        "Dept" : [
            "Sales",
            "Call Center"
        ],
        "Stage" : "0",
        "type" : "DTHyperlink",
        "Journey_Name" : "SHORT",
        "desc" : "OTP has been sent to your registered mobile number and email id. Please enter the otp"
    }
```

```
def stager(data):
   parent='.'.join(i['Stage'].split('.')[:-1])
   print (parent)
```

The results are nested dict like

```
{
  "Process_Data":{
    "id":"1565781625803558",
    "name":"head",
    "title",
    "desc":"head description",
    "children":[
      {
        "id":"1565781670793081",
        "name":"child1 title",
        "desc":"child1 description",
        "children":[
          {
            "id":"1565781711400277",
            "name":"child21 title",
            "desc":"child21 description"
          },
          {
            "id":"1565781684949457",
            "name":"child2 title",
            "desc":"child2 description",
            "children":[
              {
                "id":"1565781730359289",
                "name":"child3 title",
                "desc":"child3 description"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Journey_Name":"NEW SAMPLE",
  "Dept":[
    "Sales",
    "Call Center"
  ],
  "JourneyStatus":"create",
  "Approver_Status":""
}
```

But it is not appending in the children dict

Comment: You can navigate through dict by dict["key_1"]["key_2"]["key_3"], where "key" is defined within dict by: "key_1": "value". Then in order to navigate through regular lists just use simple list[i] where i is integer. Look for some guides on the topic too e.g. http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/

Comment: The example given by me only has 2 stages but in production level it has many stages so I want to have a code to navigate and append the child nodes in parent